# Value Given when tick box is checked :Undefined Array Key

Tags: javascript

When check box is selected, it copies value from customer to invoice party. So I am assuming that when check box selected. value is automatic. but it is saying undefined array key.

[image]

```
function EnableDisableTextBox(tickSame) {
    var shipper = document.getElementById("iP");
    var customer = document.getElementById("consignee").value;
        document.getElementById("iP").value=customer;   
    shipper.disabled = tickSame.checked ? true : false;
    if (shipper.enabled) {
    
        shipper.blur();

    }
    
}
```

Comment: From where do you get this undefined array key error? from backend?

Comment: Also no need to use a ternary on a boolean `shipper.disabled = tickSame.checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are submitting the form to the server side. Disabled inputs will not submit data when submitting the form. Instead you can use `readonly` attribute to make to non editable (Even you can make it look like `disabled` with css)

```
function EnableDisableTextBox(tickSame) {
    var shipper = document.getElementById("iP");
    var customer = document.getElementById("consignee").value;
        document.getElementById("iP").value=customer;   
    shipper.readonly= tickSame.checked ? true : false;
    if (shipper.readonly) {
    
        shipper.blur();

    }
    
}
```